# Erlang multiple Guards on `when`

Tags: erlang, pattern-guards

Fellow stackoverflow-ers,

I am currently learning Erlang.
Could someone point me why do I get an `illegal guard expression` with this guard?

`add_new_prime(Idx, Primes, Ref) when length(Primes) =:= 0 ; math:sqrt(Idx) < hd(Primes) -> Ref ++ [Idx];`

If I "un-optimise" it by doing only `add_new_prime(Idx, Primes, Ref) when length(Primes) =:= 0  -> Ref ++ [Idx];`

it works. I've seen multiple examples where there are more than one 'statement' per clause but can't see why mine is not working.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please see:

> The set of valid guard expressions (sometimes called guard tests) is a
>   subset of the set of valid Erlang expressions. The reason for
>   restricting the set of valid expressions is that evaluation of a guard
>   expression must be guaranteed to be free of side effects. Valid guard
>   expressions are:
>
> the atom true, other constants (terms and bound variables), all
>   regarded as false, calls to the BIFs specified below, term
>   comparisons, arithmetic expressions, boolean expressions, and
>   short-circuit expressions (andalso/orelse).

In you case, `math:sqrt(Idx)` is not a valid guard expression.

Read the documentation here: http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id81357

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @BlackMamba's answer, the idiomatic Erlang approach would be:

```
add_new_prime(Idx, [], Ref) -> Ref ++ [Idx];
add_new_prime(Idx, [Prime | Primes], Ref) when Idx < Prime * Prime -> Ref ++ [Idx];
...
```

> [The inclusion of length/1 in guard tests has always been more than
>   a bit dodgy.  It's better taste to avoid it.](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/erlang-programming/Qg4-AU7J5mM/DEM9MWvLdK4J)